# How do I return distinct records in Teradata SQL when joining tables that have two entries per record?

Tags: sql, join, teradata

Title is a bit of a mouthful, but essentially I have two tables, one with incident data, say, `incident_data` that contains things like the Incident ID, date, time, and other structured fields. The other `incident_text` contains the description, resolution, and other freeform text fields.

I want to search both the description and resolution fields in `incident_text` and join that with `incident_data` to get more details. They are joined by `incidentno`, and each incident can have two entries in `incident_text`, one for the description, the other for resolution.

Say this is my query:

```
SELECT    
DISTINCT INCIDENTNO as "Incident Number",
SOME_OTHER_FIELDS ETC..,
TEXTFIELD AS "Text"
TEXTFIELDTYPE AS "Text Type"

FROM INCIDENT_DATA
INNER JOIN INCIDENT_TEXT
ON INCIDENT_DATA.INCIDENTNO=INCIDENT_TEXT.INCIDENTNO

WHERE TEXT LIKE ANY ('%THIS THING%', '%THAT THING%')
```

Which gives me a table like so, despite using `DISTINCT`

```
INCIDENT-1 ... FORGOT MY PASSWORD TO THIS THING ... DESCRIPTION
INCIDENT-1 ... PASSWORD RESET TO THAT THING.... RESOLUTION
```

If I add `AND TEXTFIELDTYPE = 'DESCRIPTION'` I no longer get duplicates, but I also stop searching the resolution fields, which I'd like to still do.

What I am looking for is one line per incident, with the description of the incident, while searching in both the description and resolution fields.

Comment: ... `DISTINCT` is working properly - it's giving you two rows, each with distinct values for `TEXTFIELD` (it's for the entire result set when used like this, not per-column).  Your schema design is a little suspect - resolutions should be in their own table.  Beyond that, what sort of results do you want to see - do you want to also display resolutions?  At minimum, you're going to need to join to `Incident_Text` twice, regardless.

Comment: I'd like to see each incident with the description, while searching both the description and resolution fields, with one line per unique incident number. I absolutely agree with the schema issues...

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close - mostly it comes down to telling SQL to treat description and resolution rows separately.

```
SELECT Incident_Data.incidentNo as "Incident Number",
       some_other_fields etc..,
       d.textField AS "Text", d.textFieldType AS "Text Type"
FROM Incident_Data
INNER JOIN Incident_Text d
        ON d.incidentNo = Incident_Data.incidentNo
           AND d.textFieldType = 'Description'
LEFT JOIN Incident_Text r
       ON r.incidentNo = Incident_Data.incidentNo
          AND r.textFieldType = 'Resolution'
          AND r.textField LIKE ANY ('%THIS THING%', '%THAT THING%')
WHERE d.textField LIKE ANY ('%THIS THING%', '%THAT THING%')
      OR r.incidentNo IS NOT NULL
```

(Not tested, please verify)
- One note - you don't use `UPPER()` (or `LOWER()`, or similar); are you certain that that casing is being used?
This is also one of the times that a `WHERE` clause condition can't be moved up into an `INNER JOIN`, as we need the rows even if the description doesn't contain the search text.

Comment: I am getting an error with `INNER JOIN Incident_Text as Description`: Improper Column reference in the search condition of a joined table.

Comment: @multiphrenic - Sorry, I forgot that not all RDBMSs allow `as` for designating table aliases - besides the typo.  Also, I didn't qualify where all columns were coming from, which would also have been a problem.  How about now?

Comment: `DESCRIPTION` is a Teradata **Reserved Word** (for TPT) so should not be used.  I'd suggest changing those aliases to something easier to read (like **D** and **R**).

Comment: @BellevueBob - ... everybody has their own little quirks as to what constitutes reserved words, thanks.